# How to join two arrays in a tuple into one array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I have a tuple with two arrays and I want to make it one array:

The tuple:

```
(array([['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
       ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'],
       ['No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']], dtype='<U7'), 
array([['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']], dtype='<U7'))
```

I need to make it one array, so that it looks like :

```
   (array([['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
           ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'],
           ['No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes'],
           ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']], dtype='<U7'))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) them

```
np.vstack(tuple_of_array)
```

example from my terminal:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array = np.array  # Because I'm lazy and wanted to copy/paste your input ;-)
>>> arrays = (array([['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
...        ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'],
...        ['No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']], dtype='<U7'), 
... array([['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']], dtype='<U7'))
>>> np.vstack(arrays)
array([[u'No', u'Yes', u'No', u'No'],
       [u'No', u'Yes', u'No', u'Yes'],
       [u'No', u'No', u'No', u'Yes'],
       [u'Yes', u'No', u'No', u'Yes']], 
      dtype='<U7')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to Numpy and tried everything except for this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
t = (array([['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
       ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'],
       ['No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']], dtype='<U7'), 
array([['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']], dtype='<U7'))

np.append(t[0], t[1], axis=0)
```

Comment: Don't recommend `np.append`.  It confuses people.  It is just anther way of using `concatenate`.